# ASP.NET Core Automapper Entity Framework: failing to update object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

When passing in `AccountForUpdateDto`, my function to update the existing object fails to save in the database. The stack trace doesn't seem to provide any meaningful errors. The dto and id being passed in are both populated correctly. The account from the repository is found and populated.

#### AccountsController.cs

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAccount(int id, [FromBody] AccountForUpdateDto accountForUpdateDto)
{
    var accountFromRepo = await _repo.GetAccount(id);

    _mapper.Map(accountForUpdateDto, accountFromRepo);

    if (await _repo.SaveAll())
        return NoContent();

    throw new Exception($"Updating account {id} failed on save");
}
```

#### AutoMapperProfiles.cs

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<AccountForUpdateDto, Account>()
            .ForMember(a => a.Address, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
            .ForMember(a => a.UserAccounts, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
            .ForMember(a => a.Created, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
    }
}
```

#### Accounts.cs

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PurgeAge { get; set; }
    public DateTime CutoffDate { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

#### AccountForUpdateDto.cs

```
public class AccountForUpdateDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PurgeAge { get; set; }
    public DateTime CutoffDate { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public AccountForUpdateDto()
    {
        LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it only fail when updating the database or is _mapper.Map not correctly populating your entity?

Comment: @SBFrancies when I assign the mapped entity to a variable and debug, it appears to be fully populated.

Comment: I think it's likely that the problem is in your SaveAll method then and not with the mapping - is that possible?

Comment: I use the same SaveAll function throughout the application. I just tested it to make sure, and I am able to successfully create a new account. The function simply does `return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;`

Comment: Hmmm, not really sure what's going on then, unless the entity returned by your mapping code is no longer attached to the context but then none of your mapping would work.

Comment: Show implementation of `GetAccount`.

Comment: Collections are cleared before mapping. Try AutoMapper.Collection. Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).